# onclick functionality of a button in a page should be called when user click on 'Enter' button on the keyboard

Tags: c#, user-controls, enter, buttonclick

I have a C# .net application in which 3 text boxes and 1 button is there. When I fill the form and click on 'Enter' button on the keyboard, the button onclick functionality is not called by default. I need to *call the button onclick functionality when the user clicks 'Enter' button on the keyboard*. (These controls are in a usercontrol and it is populating in an aspx page).

Why its like this and how can I resolve it?

I am using asp:Wizard control here.

Answer (score 0):

The control asp:Panel can set the attribute "DefaultButton" to the ID of a button, that will be triggered when pressing enter. Could that be of help here?

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_panel_defaultbutton.asp